# How to join two timeseries with non-matching times and get a fully populated table in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, time-series

**The data**

I have timeseries A and B. Series A is product measurements (~ one measurement pr. second). Series B is information about what product is running (~ one datapoint pr. day). The time series look like this:

Series A - product measurements:

| tstz | measurement |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:53 | 0.579 |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:54 | 0.587 |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:55 | 0.552 |
| 2022-10-03 09:10:35 | 0.568 |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:56 | 1.02 |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:57 | 0.597 |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:58 | 0.606 |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:59 | 0.620 |

Series B - product information:

| tstz | product |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:09 | vanilla |
| 2022-10-03 10:12:06 | strawberry |

**What I want to acheieve**

I am trying to get product information attached to the product measurement, so that I can group the data according to the product, that would look like:

Product information with measurements

| tstz | measurement | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:53 | 0.579 | vanilla |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:54 | 0.587 | vanilla |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:55 | 0.552 | vanilla |
| 2022-10-03 09:10:35 | 0.568 | vanilla |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:56 | 1.02 | strawberry |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:57 | 0.597 | strawberry |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:58 | 0.606 | strawberry |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:59 | 0.620 | strawberry |

**Where I am stuck for now**

I have tried doing different thing with lead, lag and first_value, but I seem to always hit another wall that I can't figure out how to get around, but I am sure it should be possible and is probably quite simple.

| tstz | measurement | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:09 |  | vanilla |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:53 | 0.579 |  |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:54 | 0.587 |  |
| 2022-10-02 14:15:55 | 0.552 |  |
| 2022-10-03 09:10:35 | 0.568 |  |
| 2022-10-03 10:12:06 |  | strawberry |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:56 | 1.02 |  |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:57 | 0.597 |  |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:58 | 0.606 |  |
| 2022-10-03 10:15:59 | 0.620 |  |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a1.tstz,
    a1.measurement,
    a2.product
FROM
    a1
    CROSS JOIN a2
WHERE
    a1.tstz::date = a2.tstz::date;
```

setup.

```
begin;
create temp table a1
    (tstz timestamptz, measurement numeric);
create temp table a2
    (tstz timestamptz, product text);
insert into a1 values
('2022-10-02 14:15:53',     0.579),
('2022-10-02 14:15:54',     0.587),
('2022-10-02 14:15:55',     0.552),
('2022-10-03 10:15:56',     1.02);
insert into a1 values
('2022-10-03 10:15:57',     0.597),
('2022-10-03 10:15:58',     0.606),
('2022-10-03 10:15:59',     0.620);

insert into a2 values
('2022-10-02 14:15:09','vanilla'),
('2022-10-03 10:12:06','strawberry');
commit;
```

use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product then use where to filter the condition criteria.

Comment: Thanks @jian - it almost gets the job done. The remaining problem is that if something has run prior to change of product, but on the same date, it will also get product text of what runs later in the day...

Comment: @TonieDavidsenBrinch I did't get you. You can try use where clause to compare whaterver you want.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback. I have added a vanilla dataoint on '2022-10-03 09:10:35'. If I follow your suggestion that datapoint get assigned to be strawberry.

Comment: I am not sure the logic. but the following way will do. `SELECT *,case when a1.tstz <= '2022-10-03 09:10:35' then 'vanilla' else 'strawberry' end
from a1 order by 1;`

Comment: I think that would work, but I have loads of this kind of data, so how do I generalise it...?